# Now error is change cookie parser install but when I command node app it gives error "cookie-parser not found"

Tags: node.js, express, total.js

My node version 8.3.0, npm -v 5.3.0, Express.

Error

```
module.js:491
    throw err;
    ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-Parser'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:489:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Ideabazar/app.js:3:20)
        at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to install cookie-parser in your console :

```
npm install cookie-parser
```

then add `var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')` in your `server.js` file.

for ref `npm` doc : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser

Answer (score 0):

The module name is wrong. Try to `require` `cookie-parser` not `cookie-Parser`:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
```